# Swiping elements inside a TabView - Xamarin.Froms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, swipe, tabview

I have an horizontal `TabView` with 2 `TabViewItems`. In one of them I have a `WebView` that loads a certain website. The website has a long string of text that can be swiped horizontally.

```
<TabView>
    <TabViewItem>
        <WebView />
    </TabViewItem>
    <TabViewItem>
        <!-- More XAML code -->
    </TabViewItem>
<TabView>
```

Here is the problem: When `IsSwipeEnabled` is set to `True` (which is the default value of the property) the swipe gesture has no effect on the text. The focus is on the tab and swiping horizontally just brings on screen the other tab.

Is there a way to keep `IsSwipedEnabled` set to `True` but pass the focus to the text when the gesture happens on it?

Comment: add some code for more clarity of your question.

Comment: Just did. I don't think it offers much though. I believe the description was adequate. Horizontal scrolling is not detected in the WebView. Trying to horizontally scroll text in the WebView just swipes the screen to the next tab.

Answer (score 1):

Check `TabView` source code we can find actually it uses `CarouselView` to implement the scrolling effect.

[image]

However , it's not recommended to place a `Webview` on a `CarouselView/ScrollView` , the swipe gesture would generate conflict.

**The workaround is**

Disable `Swipe gesture of TableView` in Webview page , and recover it in another page .

```
<TabView IsSwipeEnabled="False" SelectionChanged="TabView_SelectionChanged">
    <TabViewItem Text="111">
        <WebView/>
    </TabViewItem>
    <TabViewItem Text="222">
        <Label Text="test"/>
    </TabViewItem>
</TabView>
```

```cs
private void TabView_SelectionChanged(object sender, Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.TabSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.NewPosition == 0)
    {
       (sender as TabView).IsSwipeEnabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
       (sender as TabView).IsSwipeEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. So the only solution is to disable swipe selectively. In that case I guess I will choose to disable it in general. I don't think allowing swiping towards only one tab would offer a good user experience. Furthermore, I have noticed that when swiping is enabled for the tabs, scrolling vertically within the `WebView` is more difficult. If the swipe gesture is performed a little bit diagonally and not perpendicularly to the top and the bottom of the screen then the content of the WebView does not get scrolled adequately.

Comment: Yes, that's true,  the phenomenon is caused by the fact that the site pages are not adapted to mobile phones.